# What to do with iPython command numbers when pasting code into SE

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Many StackOverflow questions or answers involve pasting code from iPython into the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31612800/2071807)/[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10458386/2071807).

This results in things like this:

```
In [32]: print np.random.random([2, 2])
[[ 0.36687173  0.34079422]
 [ 0.61761034  0.17372093]]

In [33]: type(np.random)
Out[33]: module
```

Clearly the `32` and `33` are not interesting to future readers of this question, but how do I go about getting rid of them?

Sometimes I edit them to look like `In []:` and I've seen some people whose answers look like `In :`

Is there a nice way of dealing with this?

Or should they just be left and actually it doesn't matter that much, and I should go and get on with my life?

Comment: When I cut and paste from IDLE I leave the prompt (`>>>`) in, to demonstrate that it's an interactive example (i.e. showing inputs and outputs) rather than a standalone code snippet and (hopefully) thereby prevent people trying to run the outputs and getting confused.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the `>>>` are much less controversially a good idea. Often I find myself  putting these in manually for the very reason you suggest!

Comment: I have wondered about this issue many times in the past. What I usually do is after trial and error and finding the "final answer", I just start a new IPython session and copy/paste lines one by one so I get the "correct" numeration.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is harm in leaving the line numbers. It's output from the IPython environment, thus (should be) well known to users in the python tags.

It's similar to pasting a stack trace that says the error is on line 5000, but you've only posted the 10 lines of relevant code around line 5000. There is no need to "fix" the stack trace if the question shows the appropriate snippet of code.

Don't waste time removing (or worse, renumbering) these lines. There are more important things that can be fixed. The question, as posted with the IPython numbers, is perfectly readable.